# Refactoring code in controller with Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, controller

I have this code in two methods (create and update). Each time I need to update or create a new user I need to encode the user password with the salt.

```
$factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
$encoder = $factory->getEncoder($entity);
$password = $encoder->encodePassword($entity->getPassword(), $entity->getSalt());
$entity->setPassword($password);
```

To avoid code duplication what should I do?

- Create a new method in controller `getEncondedPassword($entity) : return $encodedPassword`
- Add this logic to the Form using DI injecting the `$encoder` as required field
- Add this logic to model, and pass the `$encoder` in the constructor of the entity object.

Thank you!

Comment: Check http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html#modify-security-yml

Comment: @Squazic Thanks for your tip! However the objective is applicable to other scenarios. If you want to leave your opinion...

Answer (score 0):

If your create and edit are fairly simple and pretty much the same, you can combine it to one function which actually generates and validates the form.
Some code:

```
class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/create", name="_product_create")
     */
    public function createAction()
    {
        $product = new Product();

        return $this->productForm($product, $this->getRequest(), 'create');
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/edit/{product_id}", name="_product_edit_id")
     */
    public function editIdAction($product_id)
    {
        $entity_manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $product_repository = $entity_manager->getRepository('VendorBundle:Product');

        $product = $product_repository->findOneBy(
            array('id' => $product_id)
        );

        return $this->productForm($product, $this->getRequest(), 'editId');
    }

    protected function productForm(Product $product, Request $request, $twig_name)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new ProductType(), $product);

        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            $form->bindRequest($request);

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                // Do whatever we want before persisting/flushing

                return $this->redirect($redirect_url);
            }
        }

        $twig_params = array(

        );

        return $this->render(
            'VendorBundle:Product:' . $twig_name . '.html.twig', $twig_params
        );
    }

}
```

this will render `create.html.twig` and `editId.html.twig` depending on the route.
if `$product->getId() === null` we are creating a new entity, else we are editing.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the correct option is the model/entity approach.
So, I leave here the my solution:

```
public function hashPassword($container)
{
    $factory = $container->get('security.encoder_factory');

    $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($this);
    $password = $encoder->encodePassword($this->getPassword(), $this->getSalt());
    return $password;
}
```

In the controller:

```
//hash user password
$userEntity->setPassword($userEntity->hashPassword($this->container));
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now I have improved(I at least think...) the answer to this question.

I have created an class that will receive the $encoderFactory form the DI

```
#services.yml 
parameters:
    password_encoder.class: Beubi\SignatureBundle\Handler\PasswordEncoder
services:
    password_encoder:
            class: %password_encoder.class%
            arguments: [@security.encoder_factory]
```

So, I create a class that will be used in Service container:

```
class PasswordEncoder
{
    protected $encoderFactory;

    public function __construct(EncoderFactory $encoderFactory)
    {
        $this->encoderFactory = $encoderFactory;
    }

    public function encodePassword($entity){
        $encoder = $this->encoderFactory->getEncoder($entity);
        return $encoder->encodePassword($entity->getPassword(), $entity->getSalt());
    }
}
```

And then in my controller:

```
$password = $this->get('password_encoder')->encodePassword($entity);
$entity->setPassword($password);
```

This way, my User object doesn't have any knowledge of $factoryEncoder or how to encode an password.
**I'm expecting more comments on this question...**